# flutter_ffmpeg - Can we trim a part of the video in flutter while recording

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, video-editing, flutter-ffmpeg

I am making a flutter app, in which a user can **record a video** and pause in between, and when the user pauses the video a clip is formed.
So if the 4 **clips** are there, then 4th clip can be removed from the video (according to the time of the last clip).
By a **clip** I just mean the time interval between two continuous pauses. The video is being recorded continuously.
There's a way to trim a video after it's being record, for example,

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

But I think it's possible only when the video is recorded.

So, Is there any way to to trim a video (using [**flutter_ffmpeg**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg)) or the last clip, while the recording is paused ?